# Cyclotomic cosets modulo

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, cyclotomic-polynomials

I've got some troubles solving an (easy ?) exercise:

Let n=26, q=3. Now I'd like to find the cyclotomic cosets modulo n over $F_q$.

The cyclotomic cosets are defined as $C_s = (s, ns, n^2s, ..., n^{q-1}s)$, right?

So in my example, the cyclotomics would be:

$C_0 = \{0\}$
$C_1 = \{1, 26, 676\}$

Is this correct until now? I'm really not sure about the 676... And often (in literature), there is no $C_2$, $C_4$ etc. --> But why?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: "modulo $n$ over $F_3$" doesn't make much sense to me. If you're working over $F_3$, then you're working modulo 3.

Comment: Hm, the task is formulated as follows: Let n = 26, q = 3. Find the cyclotomic cosets modulo $n$ over $F_q$.

Comment: I'd recommend asking for clarification. Do you have access to any worked examples?

Comment: Hm I think that you're right...mod 26 makes no sense, but 3 does absolutely. I'll ask for clarification. But nevertheless; how would this work, let's say with modulo 3?

Comment: If you're working mod 3, there are only three elements, so there's not much to do. Anyway, it's not clear whether you're talking about the additive group mod 3, or the multiplicative group. But when you ask about cosets, you're asking about cosets of some specific subgroup, so you have to specify a subgroup for the question to make sense.

Comment: I got it: Wee look for cyclotomic cosets of 3 modulo 26, as here on page 5 (http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2008/REUPapers/Calderbank.pdf )

Comment: But the question is still actual: How do they get the cosets? (And why are they only considering $C_0$, $C_1$, $C_3$, ...) ?

Comment: Did you not notice that, in the example in those notes, they ppoint out that $C_1=C_2$? They are only interested in *distinct* cosets – there's no point in listing the same coset several times. But now that we know what the question really is, I can post an answer.

Comment: Is my answer what you're looking for?

Comment: Earth to JohnD: Come in, please.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Absolutely, thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the discussion in the comments, it turns out that the question concerns the cyclotomic cosets of $3$ modulo $26$. So, first we look at the powers of $3$, modulo $26$. Since $3^3=27\equiv1\bmod{26}$, the powers of $3$ modulo $26$ are just $\{\,1,3,9\,\}$. So this is $C_1$ (and it's also $C_3$, and $C_9$). Then

$C_2=\{\,2,6,18\,\}$, $C_4=\{\,4,12,10\,\}$, $C_5=\{\,5,15,19\,\}$, $C_7=\{\,7,21,11\,\}$, $C_8=\{\,8,24,20\,\}$, $C_{13}=\{\,13\,\}$, $C_{14}=\{\,14,16,22\,\}$, $C_{17}=\{\,17,25,23\,\}$

and I suppose you need $C_0=\{\,0\,\}$.